# Can't make my div inline

Tags: html, css

My elements in div doesn't display as inline I think I shouldn't put nav then div but I think it is going to be a lot of problem if I start all over again how do I fix it?

Btw just letting you know that I'm on my 4th day learning css and html

```css
.body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #DC143C;
  height: auto;
  width: 1264px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul.left {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left
}
.mainHeader div.right {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 18px 20px 10px 0px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px
}
.mainHeader div.border {
  width: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px inset;
  color: #DC143C;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 150px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="mainHeader">

    <nav>
      <ul class="left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img style="width:150px;height:70px" src="img/1.gif">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
        </li>
        </a>
        <li><a href="#"><h2>1</h2></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><h2>1</h2></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><h2>1</h2></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="border">
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#"><h3> 2</h3></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><h3> 2</h3></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img style="width:20px;height:20px" screen="img/16">
            </a>
          </li>
          <!-- bookmark-->
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img style="width:20px;height:20px" screen="img/17">
            </a>
          </li>
          <!-- history -->
    </nav>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the entire cause of the problem, but it could be:  You have `</nav></ul>` which should be `</ul></nav>`  (You are closing the `nav` element before closing the `ul` element which is inside `nav` -- very bad)  :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't closed div tag

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

and your css is wrong at line:

```
 .mainHeader div.right{
    list-style:none;
    display:table-row;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    margin:18px 20px 10px 0px;
}
```

It should be ul tag:

```
.mainHeader ul.right{
        list-style:none;
        display:table-row;
        position: relative;
        float:right;
        margin:18px 20px 10px 0px;
    }
```

Check my code where is close element /ul tag before nav

```css
    .body{
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
        clear:both;
    }
    .mainHeader nav{
        background-color:#DC143C;
        height:auto;
        width:1264px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .mainHeader nav ul.left{
        list-style:none;
        display:inline;
        position: relative;
        float:left
    }
    .mainHeader ul.right{
        list-style:none;
        display:table-row;
        position: relative;
        float:right;
        margin:18px 20px 10px 0px;
    }
    .mainHeader nav ul li{
        float:left;
        display:inline;
        padding-left: 10px
    }
    .mainHeader div.border{
      width: 0px; 
      height: 50px;
      float: left; 
      border: 1px inset;
      color:#DC143C;
      margin: 25px 0px 0px 150px ;
    }
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">

    <nav>
    <ul class="left">
        <li><a  href="#"><img style="width:150px;height:70px" src="img/1.gif"></a></li>
        <li><a  href="#"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."></li></a>
        <li><a  href="#"><h2>1</h2></a></li>
        <li><a  href="#"><h2>1</h2></a></li>
        <li><a  href="#"><h2>1</h2></a></li></ul>
        <div class="border"></div>
        <ul class="right">
        <li><a  href="#"><h3> 2</h3></a></li>
        <li><a  href="#"><h3> 2</h3></a></li>
        <li ><a  href="#"><img style="width:20px;height:20px" screen="img/16"></a></li>  <!-- bookmark--> 
        <li><a  href="#"><img style="width:20px;height:20px" screen="img/17"></a></li>  <!-- history -->
    </ul></nav>
```

Comment: @flummox ya i just understood the meaning of  "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" xp my english is kinda bad sry. I mean like after the border my 2 elements doesnt display in line and i want to display it in line

Answer (score 0):

```css
.body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #DC143C;
  height: auto;
  width: 1264px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul.left {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left
}
.mainHeader div.right {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 18px 20px 10px 0px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px
}
.mainHeader div.border {
  width: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px inset;
  color: #DC143C;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 150px;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">

    <nav>
        <ul class="left">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img style="width:150px;height:70px" src="img/1.gif">
                </a>
            </li>
            
          <li style="display:flex; height:70px;">
                <a href="#" style="margin:auto;"> 
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
                </a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#"><h2>1</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>1</h2></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><h2>1</h2></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="border">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="#"><h3> 2</h3></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><h3> 2</h3></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img style="width:20px;height:20px" screen="img/16">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- bookmark-->
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img style="width:20px;height:20px" screen="img/17">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- history -->
            </ul>
    
        
</div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Hope this helps.